# How to streamline this script

Tags: python, variables, global, multiprocess

I have this script and it does work it has 2 separate processes that spawn listener threads to kill the process when kill is sent to the listener via a pipe.

```
   from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
   from threading import Thread
   import time

   subAlive = True 
   testAlive = True

   def sub_listener(conn): #listens for kill from main 
       global subAlive
       while True:
             data = conn.recv()
             if data == "kill":
             subAlive = False #value for kill 
             break

    def test_listener(conn): #listens for kill from main
        global testAlive
        while True:
              data = conn.recv()
              if data == "kill":
                 testAlive = False #value for kill
                 break

    def subprocess(conn, threadNum):
        t = Thread(target=sub_listener, args=(conn,))
        count = 0
        threadVal = threadNum 
        t.start()
        while subAlive:
              print "Thread %d Run number = %d" % (threadVal, count)
              count = count + 1 


    def testprocess(conn, threadNum):
        t = Thread(target=test_listener, args=(conn,))
        count = 0
        threadVal = threadNum 
        t.start()
        while testAlive:
              print "This is a different thread %d Run = %d" % (threadVal, count)
              count = count + 1


    sub_parent, sub_child = Pipe()
    test_parent, test_child = Pipe()
    runNum = int(raw_input("Enter a number: ")) 
    threadNum = int(raw_input("Enter number of threads: "))

    print "Starting threads"

    for i in range(threadNum):
        p = Process(target=subprocess, args=(sub_child, i))
        p.start()

    print "Subprocess started"

    for i in range(threadNum): 
        p2 = Process(target=testprocess, args=(test_child, i))
        p2.start()

    print "Testproccess started"

    print "Starting run"

    time.sleep(runNum) 

    print "Terminating Subprocess run"
    for i in range(threadNum):
        sub_parent.send("kill") #sends kill to listener

    print "Terminating Testprocess run"
    for i in range(threadNum):
        test_parent.send("kill") #sends kill to listener

    p.join()
    p2.join()
```

Id like to not need a separate listener function hard coded for every process I call. I was thinking about passing global variables when the thread is spawned. The global variables are really the only differences between the listener functions. Thanks guys!

Comment: Could you please fix the indentations? Thank you :)

Comment: fixed them sorry bout that

Comment: Now it looks fine :) Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered delegating the logics and have those states somewhere in a shared memory location? If so, you can look into one of those Job Queues (such as https://github.com/binarydud/pyres or http://python-rq.org/)

Comment: That is really overkill, and there will be many different types of processes but not very many of any one individual type of process.At least when I think of job queues I think of things like github

Comment: I agree with you on the matter of scale. But personally I always apply a similar concept by just delegating the states in something like Memcached or Redis, and having `multiprocessing` or `threading` code messes all nicely separated and truly decoupled into different modules (often long running). That way I deal less with threads and code becomes more manageable. Bottom line is, whether you trust those in-memory stores or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access globals through the `globals()` dictionary.

```
>>> foo = 'value'
>>> def change(name):
...    globals()[name] = 'changed'
... 
>>> change('foo')
>>> foo
'changed'
```

but I would suggest:

```
alive = {}
def sub_listener(conn, key): #listens for kill from main 
    while True:
         data = conn.recv()
         if data == "kill":
         alive[key] = False #value for kill 
         break
```

---

e.g.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
from threading import Thread
import time

alive = {
    'sub': 1,
    'test': 1,
}

def listener_factory(key):
    def listener(conn): #listens for kill from main
        while True:
            data = conn.recv()
            if data == "kill":
                alive[key] = False #value for kill
                break
    return listener

def process_factory(key):
    listener = listener_factory(key)
    def subprocess(conn, threadNum):
        t = Thread(target=listener, args=(conn,))
        count = 0
        threadVal = threadNum
        t.start()
        while alive[key]:
            print "Thread[%s] %d Run number = %d" % (key, threadVal, count)
            count = count + 1
    return subprocess

def main():
    sub_parent, sub_child = Pipe()
    test_parent, test_child = Pipe()
    runNum = int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))
    threadNum = int(raw_input("Enter number of threads: "))
    print "Starting threads"
    for i in range(threadNum):
        p = Process(target=process_factory('sub'), args=(sub_child, i))
        p.start()
    print "Subprocess started"
    for i in range(threadNum):
        p2 = Process(target=process_factory('test'), args=(test_child, i))
        p2.start()
    print "Testproccess started"
    print "Starting run"
    time.sleep(runNum)
    print "Terminating Subprocess run"
    for i in range(threadNum):
        sub_parent.send("kill") #sends kill to listener
    print "Terminating Testprocess run"
    for i in range(threadNum):
        test_parent.send("kill") #sends kill to listener
    p.join()
    p2.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: how is that much different than what I have? It seems that you are just condensing the global variables and not the listener threads into a single listner thanks the dictionary is a neat trick though

Comment: Yeah I see how that works that is exactly what I was thinking of thanks!!